# liquibase unique constraint on two tables

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, unique-constraint

I have the following liquibase changelog file:

```
<changeSet>
    <createTable tableName="FAQ">
        <column name="ID" type="UUID">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="NAME" type="varchar2">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="CONTENT">
        <column name="LOCALE" type="varchar2"/>
        <column name="QUESTION" type="varchar2"/>
        <column name="RESPONSE" type="varchar2"/>
        <column name="FAQ_ID" type="UUID">
            <constraints foreignKeyName="FK_CONTENT_FAQ" referencedTableName="FAQ"
                         referencedColumnNames="ID"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="FAQ_ID, LANGUAGE"
                   constraintName="PK_CONTENT"
                   tableName="CONTENT"/>
</changeSet>
```

I would like to create a new liquibase changeset to have a unique constraint on `FAQ.NAME`, `CONTENT.LOCALE` and `CONTENT.QUESTION`.

Is it possible and how can I achieve this with liquibase?

Comment: A unique constraint can only be defined for a **single** table. As you can't define a unique constraint across two tables in Postgres you also can not do that in Liquibase

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, is there any workaround to ensure the unicity of the triplet?

Comment: If ID and NAME in the FAQ table have a unique combination (e.g., NAME is primary key) , in CONTENT table make the combination of local and question unique, then you have unique triplets  (since FAQ_ID as a key is unique)